# R CCA Plot: How to get rid of overlapping labels in plot()?

Tags: r, plot

I am doing a CCA on a table of abundance data of species and environmental parameters, very similar to the doubs data, package `ade4.`

```
cil.cca.r<-cca(cil~.,envm.r)
```

Where `cil` is a table with abundance data with 16 observations (sample sites) and 76 variables (abundances) and `envm.r` is my table with 16 observations (sample sites) and 11 variables (environmental parameters).

My problem is that I have a lot of species and I want the names of the species in the plot to be more readable. 
Or if this does´t work, I would need to find out which species e.g. please allow me to say "prefer" the environmental parameter PK/ml. How can I get to that information when the species names are not readable. 
The command I started with is the following:

```
plot(cil.cca.r,scaling=1,display=c("sp","lc","cn"),main="Triplot CCA spe ~envm.r - scaling 1",repel = TRUE )
```

[image: Plot of my CCA, species in red, environmental parameters in blue]

Next I also tried to separate the commands to make it more readable.

```
plot(cil.cca.rh, type="n",xlim=c(-2,2))
text(cil.cca.rh, "species", col="red", cex=0.6)
text(cil.cca.rh, dis="cn",cex=0.7,adj=0.8,col="blue")
```

I don´t get anywhere with trying out the parameters.

Then I found the function `orditorp()`

```
plot(cil.cca.rh, type="n",xlim=c(-2,2))
orditorp(cil.cca.rh, "species", col="red", cex=0.6)
orditorp(cil.cca.rh,display="sites",cex=0.8,adj=0.1,col="darkgreen",air=0.7)
```

[Plot with orditorp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRg2L.jpg)

This makes the plot look nicer, but still I don´t get the information about my species, since a lots of them get points.
I hoped for some solution like package `ggrepel` e.g. function `repel()` in `ggplot2` but this doesn´t work for a CCA.
Error "ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class cca"....
I also hoped for some function like `fviz_pca_ind()` of package `factoextra`
but for CCA data.
But I could´t find anything and would be very grateful for solutions either for better plotting the labels or for getting the species names with the locations!
Of course, what I could do is give the species shorter names or numbers instead of names, but it would be nicer to get at one view which species it is...
Or perhaps "zoomig in" part of the graphic?

Comment: this might be helpful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html.

Comment: @mt1022 thank you for your comment! What I understood ggrepel works with ggplot2 and unfortunately ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class cca.

Comment: Maybe you can extract the coordinates or text and arrows somehow and draw the plot with ggplot2 manually.

Comment: @mt1022 My question was if somebody either nows how to change the plot or how to extract the coordinates for the species! Thanks for your comment, I think this was not clearly formulated with my words.